# Utilizar variável global em mais de um arquivo js

Tags: javascript, html5

Tenho o arquivo **GeraGridDados.js** e nesse arquivo criei uma variável global e uma função.

```
nomeTela = "";

function redirecionaTela() {
    //redireciona para tela que chamou a tela de Dados.
    location.href = nomeTela + ".html";
};
```

Gostaria de chamar essa variável **nomeTela** em outro documento JS **GeraGraficoAcucar.js** e alimentar ela com um valor. E quando eu chamar a função **redirecinaTela()** do **GeraGridDados.js** em outra tela HTML que esse valor esteja ainda alimentado.

Arquivo GeraGraficoAcucar.js:

```
function redirecionaTelaDados()
{
    nomeTela = "acucar";
    location.href = "dadosGrafico.html";
}
```

Nos dois arquivos HTML meu eu tenho o link para o arquivo .js, conforme abaixo:

```
<script src="scripts/GeraGridDados.js"></script>
```

Porém dessa forma que fiz, a variável global fica vazia quando chamo na que vai utilizar esse nomeTela.

Essa forma que estou fazendo é correta?
Existe alguma forma melhor pra fazer isso?

Comment: Mesmo essa não sendo sua primeira pergunta, seja bem vindo ao StackOverFlow em Português. Fiz uma edição na sua pergunta removendo agradecimento e saudação, tendo em vista que nossa comunicação não é instantânea. Sugiro que você dê uma lida [nesse tópico no meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/846/sauda%c3%a7%c3%b5es-e-agradecimentos) onde esse assunto (saudações e agradecimentos) foi tratado. Caso haja ainda algo em que possamos ajudar, [pergunte lá no meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @emanuelsn obrigado, vou seguir esse padrão sugerido.

Comment: Sua pergunta, pode conter 3 diferentes respostas, de acordo com o ponto de vista de entendimento, podemos afirmar que: `"Você quer saber como utilizar uma variável global em mais de um arquivo js"` **isso já é um comportamento natural do javascript**, e também você quer `"Utilizar uma variavel que não se perca ao redirecionar para outra página"`**(apenas neste caso a resposta do @Antony Alkmim estaria correta)** Porem lendo o **conteúdo** de sua pergunta, você pode não precisar fazer isto, **(de acordo com minha resposta)**, então por favor verifique o que você realmente quer antes de marcar.

Comment: O que eu precisava é o que foi sugerido pelo Antony Alkmim e também por você Paulo Roberto. Todas as respostas foram uteis, obrigado.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Se for redirecionar você perde a informação contida na variável pois o arquivo `GeraGridDados.js` vai carregar novamente.

Uma solução fácil pra isso é usar localStorage

```
// Armazenar
localStorage.setItem("nomeTela", "Joao");
// Obter
nomeTela = localStorage.getItem("nomeTela");
//Limpar
localStorage.clear();
```

Tem outras formas, com sessionStorage, onde os dados ficam armazenados somente durante a sessão, ou seja quando fechar o navegador os dados se perdem.

Dê uma olhada na [documentação](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) do LocalStorage.

Comment: Deu certo!!!

Só mais uma dúvida, em algum momento esse localStorage("nomeTela") poderá ser apagado, ou então será apagado pelo próprio processo?

Comment: Editei a resposta com o método para limpar!

Comment: Só uma coisa: *esta sua resposta está correta, porém está correta **em partes***, pois lendo a pergunta do OP podemos obter 3 respostas diferentes.

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade, lendo o título de sua pergunta, você diz *como utilizar variável global em mais de um arquivo js*, bom, respondendo a isto, posso afirmar a você que independentemente de quantos arquivos .js você tiver incluso na página, todo o código sera compilado como um **todo** e qualquer variável que seja declarada desta forma: `variavel = valor` se tornará global em "todos os arquivos .js", mas no seu caso você está fazendo um redirecionamento, por isso todos os valores definidos se perderão.

Então se fosse o caso, você deveria utilizar `Cookies`, ou `localStorage` para armazenar dados que você queira utilizar em "outra tela".

MAS, **aparentemente você não precisa fazer isto**, pois pelo visto você quer o "nome da tela" ou seja o nome do arquivo `.html` que você se encontra no momento, do qual pode ser resgatado a hora que você desejar apenas utilizando o `location.href`:

```
var addr     = location.href;
var nomeTela = addr.substring(addr.lastIndexOf('/')+1, addr.indexOf('.html'))
alert(nomeTela);
```

Comment: Paulo Roberto, o exemplo de `localStore` atende exatamente o que preciso. Obrigado pela ajuda também.

Comment: Certo, porém tente explicar melhor o que você realmente quer, pois sua pergunta está confusa, contendo entendimentos diferentes.